# Convertir cadenas de números con espacios en una columna (1234) a int

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, cast, casting

Intento transformar strin de numeros como `1 111` en int en la columna de una dataframe:

```
df_ga['Count'] = [float(str(val).replace(' ','').replace(',','.')) for val in df_ga['Count'].values]
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1\u202f111'
```

Tambien intenté con replace & regex

```
df_ga['Count'] = df_ga['Count'].replace(' ', '')
```

y

```
df_ga.Count = df_ga.Count.replace('\s+', ' ', regex=True)
```

y me devuelven:

```
ValueError: Unable to parse string "1 111" at position 134
```

Intenté con coerce pero me da NaN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seguro que hay una manera más sencilla, pero te dejo un código:

```
import pandas as pd

x = ['1 111', '2222', '333 3']

df = pd.DataFrame({"campo1":x})

a = [i.replace(" ","") for i in list(df["campo1"])] # quitamos los espacios en blanco
b = [int(i) if i.strip() else 0. for i in a] # pasamos a int

df["campo1"] = b # sustituimos todos los valores en la columna
df
```

Este código crea un dataframe con 1 columna con los valores `1 111, 2222, 333 3` todos como texto. Primero crea una lista `a` donde están guardados pero sin espacios en blanco. Luego una lista `b` donde los transforma a `int`

El output que consigo:

```
    campo1
0   1111
1   2222
2   3333
```

Como ves, lo reconoce como números.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:** Vale, creo que lo que pasa es que por la codificación, no es un espacio en blanco tal cual, sino el caracter `u202f2`, que equivale a

> [u202f2](https://charbase.com/202f-unicode-narrow-no-break-space)

Entonces, he modificado el código para que la lista `a` se construya eliminando ese carácter especial.

```
import pandas as pd

x = ['1\u202f111', '2222', '333\u202f3']

df = pd.DataFrame({"campo1":x})
df
    campo1
0   1 111
1   2222
2   333 3

a = [i.replace('\u202f',"") for i in list(df["campo1"])] # quitamos los espacios en blanco
b = [int(i) if i.strip() else 0. for i in a] # pasamos a int

df["campo1"] = b # sustituimos todos los valores en la columna
df

    campo1
0   1111
1   2222
2   3333
```

Prueba ahora a ver. Piensa que solo te funcionará para el caracter `u202f2`. Si hay más a sustituir, tendrás que cambiarlos todos antes de convertirlo a string.

Comment: Por desgracia me devuelve: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1\u202f111'`

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica Por favor, mira la respuesta actualizada